# How to create sublist with all values taken from List<User> in flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dictionary, sublist

I have a question how to keep all data in sublist created from main list in Flutter?
I created simple code to explain what i am looking for.
I managed to save one value - swimmer.nameModel but i need all of them.
Is any good tutorial to learn this subject properly?
Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ModelUser {
  final String nameModel;
  final String surnameModel;
  final String? imageModel;
  final String? mobileModel;
  final String? emailModel;
  final String? addressModel;
  final List<String?> joinedGroupsModel;

  const ModelUser({
    Key? key,
    required this.nameModel,
    required this.surnameModel,
    this.imageModel,
    this.mobileModel,
    this.emailModel,
    this.addressModel,
    this.joinedGroupsModel = const [],
  });
}

List<ModelUser> allUsers = [
  const ModelUser(
      nameModel: 'John',
      surnameModel: 'Newman',
      joinedGroupsModel: ['Swimmers', 'Runners', 'Footballers']),
  const ModelUser(nameModel: 'Barry', surnameModel: 'Newday'),
  const ModelUser(
      nameModel: 'Mike',
      surnameModel: 'Smith',
      joinedGroupsModel: ['Swimmers', 'Runners', 'Footballers']),
  const ModelUser(
      nameModel: 'Harry',
      surnameModel: 'Portland',
      joinedGroupsModel: ['Footballers']),
  const ModelUser(
      nameModel: 'Cathy',
      surnameModel: 'Portman',
      joinedGroupsModel: ['Swimmers', 'Runners', 'Footballers']),
  const ModelUser(
      nameModel: 'Jessie',
      surnameModel: 'Olert',
      joinedGroupsModel: ['Swimmers']),
];

class PageWhere extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'PageWhere';

  const PageWhere({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final swimmers =
        allUsers.where((user) => user.joinedGroupsModel.contains('Swimmers'));
    final List<String> listOfSwimmers = swimmers.map((swimmer) {
      return swimmer.nameModel;
    }).toList();

    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('Swimmers'),
        ...listOfSwimmers
            .map((value) => Text(value, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))
            .toList(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

So instead of List-String listOfSwimmers how can I create List-ModelUser listOfSwimmers with all values provided in allUsers list?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for how to access UserModel containing Swimmers.
So you just need to change List to List and return whole swimmer object.
see changes in code:

```
class PageWhere extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'PageWhere';

  const PageWhere({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final swimmers =
        allUsers.where((user) => user.joinedGroupsModel.contains('Swimmers'));
    final List<ModelUser> listOfSwimmers = swimmers.map((swimmer) {
      return swimmer;
    }).toList();
    print(listOfSwimmers.runtimeType);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Swimmers'),
            ...listOfSwimmers
                .map((value) => Text("${value.nameModel} ${value.surnameModel}",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))
                .toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGtWa.png)

Comment: thank you Yogita! That's what I was looking for! Is it good practice to use this approach with pages/screens? As my app is about our church so there will be around 10 lists of ModelScreen in use but some will have same children. This is my first app and want to make it and understand it in the right way:)